# How do I log only received information in RealTerm

Tags: serial

I am trying to test a sensor circuit I'm working on. Essentially, I am using `RealTerm` to send commands to the µcontroller and it is returning the value read by the sensor. When logging to a file in `RealTerm`, I noticed the commands being sent were showing up as well as the data being returned. I was wondering if anyone knew a way to record only the incoming data using `RealTerm`, and not the outgoing commands. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Unfortunately, there is no way around using `RealTerm` specifically because of a company policy.

Comment: Turn off "local echo" and also make sure the microcontroller isn't echoing commands back.

Comment: Can you post-process the capture file to filter out the unwanted up-going commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded RealTerm and did some testing:

- "Half Duplex" (strangely enough) appears to be the equivalent of "local echo", however that only works to turn off outgoing data for screen display (although see the last item below).
- The diagnostic log file seems to capture incoming and outgoing data regardless. If you need to use this method you might look at ["Diagnostic Files: Trace and Log"](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/#Diagnostic_Files), but I don't know if that will help.
- With "Direct Capture" enabled, the "Capture" option appears to only capture incoming data and you can include a time stamp if the data from your sensor is terminated with a carriage-return and line-feed. It does not seem to include all the diagnostic data of the log file.
- If you only need to capture incoming data, use the "Capture" option and turn off "Direct Capture". This will capture everything that goes to the screen display; therefore to only capture incoming data, un-check "Half Duplex" on the "Display" tab.

Comment: This was a great answer, and I appreciate the time you took to answer. I would also like to add, for the sake of other people who may stumble upon this, that the problem seems to be almost exclusively in Windows 7 64. Thank you!

Comment: @user40171 Oh great, our systems administrator just ordered me a Windows 7 64-bit machine to get me off of XP ;-(  ... By the way, I just found [THIS](http://nushair.blogspot.com/2010/06/some-tips-to-use-realterm.html) which discusses a workaround for the problem that you cannot save settings with RealTerm.